# Создание объекта класса с закрытым конструктором

Tags: c#

Есть, например, класс `DbProviderFactory` с защищенным конструктором (подобных классов в библиотеке Net куча) для создания объекта этого класса нужен статический метод другого класса `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Bla");`.

У меня возник вопрос, каким образом этот метод создает объект `DbProviderFactory`, если конструктор там закрыт ? Я вначале подумал, что в классе реализована "фабрика", но ничего подобного я не обнаружил.

Как он создается с использованием метода  `GetFactory("Bla");`? Если можно на примере кода.

Comment: Я полагаю, что это делается с использованием `reflection`.

Comment: Я тоже так подумал, но как это реализовано и какие атрибуты использовать ума не приложу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая весьма удобная утила от JetBrains, называется dotPeek. она позволяет декомпилировать .NET сборки и видеть их исходники, можете воспользоваться.

Что же касается конкретно DbProviderFactories.GetFactory, то в нем используется рефлексия.

Вот исходник:

```
public static DbProviderFactory GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
{
  ADP.CheckArgumentNull((object) providerRow, "providerRow");
  DataColumn index = providerRow.Table.Columns["AssemblyQualifiedName"];
  if (index != null)
  {
    string str = providerRow[index] as string;
    if (!ADP.IsEmpty(str))
    {
      Type type = Type.GetType(str);
      if ((Type) null != type)
      {
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField("Instance", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        if ((FieldInfo) null != field && field.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof (DbProviderFactory)))
        {
          object obj = field.GetValue((object) null);
          if (obj != null)
            return (DbProviderFactory) obj;
        }
        throw ADP.ConfigProviderInvalid();
      }
      throw ADP.ConfigProviderNotInstalled();
    }
  }
  throw ADP.ConfigProviderMissing();
}
```

В случае же с другими фабриками чаще всего используют не рефлексию в силу ее "дороговизны", а открытые конструкторы классов-наследников, либо вовсе предоставляют статический метод для получения экземпляра из самого класса

Comment: О, круто ! Спасибо большое !

Comment: А еще можно [сразу исходники смотреть](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DbProviderFactories.cs,6c6fbb6f5760741d)  :)

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что создаётся не сам класс, а его потомок. Protected-конструктор и нужен для того, чтобы легально сконструировать объект могли лишь его потомки.

---

Как отмечено в правильном ответе @DreamChild, на самом деле объект создаётся при помощи рефлексии. С рефлексией можно вызвать даже приватный конструктор. Но тем не менее, законный юзкейс для защищённого конструктора — абстрактный класс.

Comment: Спасибо большое ! Не знал, что можно вызвать закрытый конструктор через рефлексию, я думал, что его нужно обложить атрибутами для этого.

Comment: @polyakov_s: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD рефлексия - это вообще то-то вроде deus ex machine. Грязный трюк, который иногда все же очень полезен

Comment: @DreamChild: Я имел в виду не что это запрещённое средство, а скорее что это _внеязыковое_ средство. _C# the language_ о рефлексии ничего не знает, это свойство стандартной библиотеки. Впрочем, граница между языком и его стандартной библиотекой достаточно размыта.

Comment: @VladD ну на мой взгляд разделение на языковые-неязыковые средства особого смысла наверное не имеет, а вот сами по себе недостатки рефлексии - очень даже. Помимо всем известной медлительности есть с рефлексией и еще более важная проблема - рефлексия зачастую опирается на внутреннюю реализацию класса, которая не предназначена для посторонних глаз и  может меняться, тогда как рефлексирующий код об этом никогда не узнает, что чревато внезапно появившимися исключениями там, где их никогда не было

Comment: @DreamChild: Угу. Непубличные методы имеют право в любой момент исчезнуть. Потому язык и не даёт к ним доступа.

Comment: @VladD тут скорее наоборот, но это уже софистика)

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю ещё создание объекта с закрытым конструктором из внешнего кода:

```
class Spy
{
    private Spy()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Shit, someone created me!");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctor = typeof(Spy).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null, new Type[0], null);
        ctor.Invoke(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как то не нормально сделано.
Потомки System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory содержат поле Instance, которое инициализируется как то так
public static readonly SqlClientFactory Instance = new SqlClientFactory();

Comment: Вы уверены, что это ответ, а не комментарий к вопросу или другому ответу?